# Transpose table - Pivot SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose

I have a table that looks like this:
[SourceTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktsf9.jpg)

```
CREATE TABLE [Temp].[tblMyleneTest]
(
    [DispOrder] [INT] NULL,
    [ReferencePeriod] [VARCHAR](7) NULL,
    [TypeOfGSUF] [VARCHAR](8) NULL,
    [FactAllocReferencePeriod] [VARCHAR](4) NULL,
    [Variable] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Value] [INT] NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [Temp].[tblMyleneTest]
VALUES (1, '201710F', 'Reduced', '2015', 'OperatingEntityNumberCount', '13540688'),
       (2, '201710F', 'Reduced', '2015', 'EnterpriseCodeCount', '6041138'),
       (3, '201710F', 'Reduced', '2015', 'EstablishmentCodeCount', '6554081'),
       (4, '201710F', 'Reduced', '2015', 'LocationCodeCount', '6600130'),
       (5, '201710F', 'Reduced', '2015', 'NAICSNotNullCount', '9943634'),
       (6, '201710F', 'Reduced', '2015', 'ReportingEntityNumbeCount', '2608'),
       (7, '201710F', 'Reduced', '2015', 'LocationCode_NotEverAliveCount', '2339'),
       (8, '201710F', 'Reduced', '2015', 'OperatingEntityNumberCountFF', '3078'),
       (1, '201706F', 'Reduced', '2014', 'OperatingEntityNumberCount', '13557946'),
       (2, '201706F', 'Reduced', '2014', 'EnterpriseCodeCount', '6046857'),
       (3, '201706F', 'Reduced', '2014', 'EstablishmentCodeCount', '6560136'),
       (4, '201706F', 'Reduced', '2014', 'LocationCodeCount', '6606226'),
       (8, '201706F', 'Reduced', '2014', 'OperatingEntityNumberCountFF', '3078')
```

I would like the `ReferencePeriod`, `FactAllocReferencePeriod` and `TypeOfGSUF` to be grouped. As you can see, have 2 records for the same variable name.  On for `ReferencePeriod` 201710F and the other for 201706F.  I would like those counts to be side by side.  I would like something like this:

[Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfKLx.jpg)

I am able to pivot the table to bring the `ReferencePeriod` up.  But not the related FactAllocReferencePeriod/TypeOfGSUF...

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Temp].[tblMyleneTest]
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR ReferencePeriod IN ([201710F], [201706F])) p
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Excellent job for your first question. It is always great to see people post a table along with sample data. And bonus points for posting the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing [this answer on pivoting rows into columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30119/pivot-rows-into-multiple-columns)

```
SELECT
    [Variable], piv.[201706F], piv.[201710F]
FROM 
(
    select [DispOrder], [Variable], [ReferencePeriod], [Value] from  #tblMyleneTest
) src
PIVOT (
    MAX([Value])
    FOR ReferencePeriod IN ([201710F],[201706F])
) piv
```

order by [DispOrder]

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional aggregation for this instead of pivot. The syntax is less obtuse to me.

```
select variable
    , R201710f = max(case when ReferencePeriod = '201710F' then Value end)
    , F201706f = max(case when ReferencePeriod = '201706F' then Value end)
from tblMyleneTest
group by variable
order by variable
```

Comment: Yes, that would work.  But I am losing values!  But I guess I can update the transposed table to add the 2 rows missing...

Comment: What do you mean you are losing values? No query is going to be able to just make up data like you have in your examples for the rows that are...well...who knows where that data comes from.

Answer (score 0):

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GmFc.jpg)

I am losing the TypeOfGSUF and the FactAllocReferencePeriod...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final piece of code:

```
    -- Transpose tblSUFGenericCountsReportYYYYMM to get proper display --
SET @p_SQLCMD  = N' DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + @p_SUFReportTable + '' 
               + N' SELECT [DispOrder], [Variable], piv.[' + @p_ReferencePeriod2 + '], piv.[' + @p_ReferencePeriod1 + '] '
               + N' INTO ' + @p_SUFReportTable + ' from ( '
               + N' SELECT [DispOrder], [Variable], [ReferencePeriod], [Value] FROM  Temp.tblSUFGenericCountsReport ) src '
               + N' PIVOT ( MAX([Value]) FOR ReferencePeriod IN ([' + @p_ReferencePeriod1 + '],[' + @p_ReferencePeriod2 + ']) ) piv'
               + N' ORDER BY [DispOrder];'

EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @p_SQLCMD
```

and then add the missing values:

```
-- Insert the TypeOfGSUF and FactorAllocationReferenceYear values to the report --
SET @p_SQLCMD  = N' INSERT INTO '+ @p_SUFReportTable +' (DispOrder, variable, "'+ @p_ReferencePeriod2 +'", "'+ @p_ReferencePeriod1 +'", Flag)'
               + N' VALUES (0 ,''TYPE OF GSUF'', "'+ @p_SUFMonthReduced +'", "'+ @p_SUFMonthReduced +'", Null),'
               + N' (1 ,''T4 RY used for allocation view'', ' + @p_PrevFactAllocReferencePeriod + ', ' + @p_FactAllocReferencePeriod + ', Null) ;'

PRINT @p_SQLCMD
EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @p_SQLCMD
```